# mysql-bin.xxxxxx filling up drive space

Tags: mysql

Is it safe to purge mysql-bin files? NOTE: this database houses Jira and Confluence data. I know i can go into mysql client and use the proper purge option, but is it safe for Jira and Confluence? Or is there a proper method within Jira app to purge those files. I have mysql-bin.xxxxxx files since 2011 to date and each file equating to 1.1GB.

Comment: 1.1GB each file, a total collectively since 2011 == 180GB ...and growing

Yes, I have backups etc. I just want to proceed with caution if anyone has had experience with it. I've gotten a somewhat unsure answer by someone saying 'I think this is just part of how mysql works'

Comment: It's to do with how your MySQL is tuned. I'd take a snapshot with a proper backup tool, restore onto another machine, and check that you haven't lost anything. It looks like your binary log retention period is set too generously, or it's not rotating them correctly. See also [`PURGE BINARY LOGS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/purge-binary-logs.html).

Comment: i was able to test this on a cloned machine and it was fine. So it is safe to purge the mysql-bin files properly. Thanks.